# Subtyping within a single file Java?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make a set of data types that are subtyped to person in one file. The following code doesn't have any compilation errors but when I create another file to test the code it won't compile because it says all the subtypes aren't declared.

```
package people;


public abstract class Person {
        public interface Teacher {

        }
        public class Professor implements Teacher {

        }

        public class Student {

        }

        public class TeachingAssistant extends Student implements Teacher {

        }
}
```

This is the testing class and it shows the red lines below Teacher, Professor, and TeachingAssistant. I dont understand why its not working.

```
package people;

/**
 *
 * @author Alex
 */

public class Edutypes {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        testTypes();
    }

    public static void testTypes() {
        Person a = new Professor(), b=new Student(), c=new TeachingAssistant();
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
        Teacher d = new Professor(), e=new TeachingAssistant();
        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(e);

    }
}
```

I really dont get it, can some one help?

Comment: You need an instance of the abstract class in order to instantiate your **inner** classes. And, oddly `Professor` isn't a `Person`.

Answer (score 5):

None of your inner classes actually extend `Person`; they just happen to live in the `Person` class.

You will have to explicitly a) make your inner classes `static`, b) have them extend `Person`, c) refer to them qualified, e.g. `Person a = new Person.Professor()`.

```
    public static class Professor extends Person implements Teacher {

    }

    public static class Student extends Person {

    }

    public static class TeachingAssistant extends Student implements Teacher {

    }
```

Comment: And `Person.Professor` doesn't half look weird, implying that maybe this isn't the best kind of design from an OOP perspective.

Comment: Shouldn't Teacher be a inner static interface? Using as "implements Person.Teacher".

Comment: @AlissonVieira inner interfaces are automatically static, and you don't have to explicitly qualify references to other inner classes of the same class.

Comment: I tried using "extends Person" for Student and Professor like you suggested when I was trying on my own but I still get the same error. I'm using NetBeans 8.1. I thought embedding a class within a class was like extending it? Is it possible to make it all into one file? This is an exercise for using polymorphism and the question said to do it all in one file and I'm not understanding how because if I take Professor, Student and TeachingAssistant out of the Person class it gives me an error saying the file name must be the same as class (this I already knew) so how would I put it into one file?

Comment: Please describe the exact error message you get.  Putting one class in another does _not_ make one extend the other.  Make sure you're correcting all three issues I described.